# Custom urls for MVC application in subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routes, url-rewrite-module

I'm not sure the correct way to phrase what I'm trying to accomplish, and I'm definitely not a MVC expert. So, I'm not sure the best way to handle this. I feel like there should be a more elegant, MVC based approach than what I've thought of so far.

I have a site with a physical structure similar to the following:

www.example.com (web forms application)
-red (native folder in the parent web forms application)
-blue (mvc subapplication)

So, by default, urls would be like the following:
www.example.com/red/test.aspx
www.example.com/blue/controller/action

For some controllers, I need 
www.example.com/**blue**/controller/action 
to instead have a publicly visible url at
www.example.com/**green**/controller/action

I have so far accomplished this with a rewrite rule in the parent/root website. However, the mvc subapplication doesn't natively understand that some requests live under a pseudo folder. So, when I render a form with html.BeginForm for pages requested at www.example.com/green/controller/action, it renders the form's action as /blue/controller/action. Other than outbound rewrite rules, is there someway to "teach" the mvc subapplication about a new root path for select controllers? Is there someway to configure some of this when registering routes on startup? Any other suggestions on the best way to handle this? Now, keep in mind, the rewrite from blue to green is not the entire subapplication. Some controllers will need to be rewritten to have a root of orange, etc.

Obviously, the use of colors is just an example. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Areas in MVC would make things easier and more organized.

Refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) for more info

Here is another useful [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I think I'm missing something with this. How does it fix the url issue? Could you provide an example?